Higher order Frechet derivatives viewed as bilinear maps, on Taylors theorem
So I have been studying some introductory non-linear analysis. I am currently looking at higher order Frechet derivatives and I want to proof-check/ make sure I got  something right. So given $X,Y$ Banach spaces, $U\subset X$ open, $x_0\in U$ and $F:U\rightarrow Y$ Frechet differentiable on U. Then the Frechet derivative at $x_0$ is a linear map from $X$ to $Y$, i.e. $dF[x_0]\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, the second derivative is the derivative of the induced map $dF:U\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ which is also a map between Banach spaces we get $d^2F[x_0]=d(dF[x_0])$ and so $d^2F[x_0]\in \mathcal{L}(X,\mathcal{L}(X,Y))\cong Bil(X\times X,Y)$, and for the third derivative $d^3F[x_0]\in\mathcal{L}(X,\mathcal{L}(X,\mathcal{L}(X,Y)))$ so the above observation would mean that we are looking at the space $\mathcal{L}(X,Bil(X\times X,Y))$. Is this space isomorphic to $ \{ f:X\times X\times X\rightarrow Y\text{ : such that} f \text{ is linear in all three coordinates} \}$. If so and we denote:
$$
A_n={f:X\times \cdots \times X\rightarrow Y, \text{ : f is linear in all coordinates}}
$$
is is true that $d^nF[x_0]\in A_n$. Also is there an isomorphism $A_n\cong \mathcal{L}(X,\mathcal{L}(X,\ldots,\mathcal{L}(X,Y)\ldots))$ and which would imply that $A_n$ is Banach ?

Yes, but you are missing the continuity of the linear maps everywhere.

What you have said is essentially correct. The Fréchet derivative allows you to discuss the behaviour of a function near a point using a linear approximation. Given the information in your above question, the Fréchet derivative of $F$ at $x_{0}$, if it exists, is the unique continuous linear map $dF[x_{0}] \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ such that there exists some $\varphi :U\to Y$ such that
$$F(x) = F(x_{0}) + dF[x_{0}](x-x_{0}) + \varphi (x)$$
for all $x\in U$ with the property that
$$\lim_{x\to x_{0}} \frac{\varphi (x)}{\|x - x_{0}\|} = 0.$$
If $F$ is Fréchet differentiable at every point in $U$, $F$ is said to be Fréchet differentiable on $U$ and this induces a map $dF:U\to \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ which associates each $x_{0}\in U$ with a continuous linear map $dF[x_{0}]$ such that $dF[x_{0}]$ is the Fréchet derivative of $F$ at $x_{0}$. As $Y$ is a Banach space, $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is also a Banach space. Then it is possible to ask whether the map $dF:U\to \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is again Fréchet differentiable at some given $x_{0}\in U$.
One notation for the derivative of this map $dF$ at $x_{0}$ is $d^{2}F[x_{0}]$ and it is an element of $\mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X,Y))$. You make another useful observation here that each $f\in \mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X,Y))$ induces an element $g$ of $\mathcal{L}^{2}(X,Y)$ (the set of continuous bilinear maps from $X$ into $Y$) by the formula $g(x,y) := [f(x)](y)$. In fact, if you equip $\mathcal{L}^{2}(X,Y)$ with the norm $\|g\| := \sup \{\|g(x,y)\|_{Y} : x,y\in B_{X} \}$ where $B_{X} = \{x\in X : \|x\|_{X} \leq 1\}$, then the correspondence between $\mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X,Y))$ and $\mathcal{L}^{2}(X,Y)$ is a surjective isometry. Both of these spaces are Banach spaces. This can either be checked individually, or it can be used that if $E$ is a normed space and $F$ is a Banach space, then $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ is a Banach space, applying this with $E = X$ and $F = \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ as well using that surjective isometries preserve completeness. As a consequence, rather than thinking about the second derivative as a map $d^{2}F:U\to \mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X,Y))$, often it can be treated as a map from $U$ into $\mathcal{L}^{2}(X,Y)$.
Essentially all that was stated in the second-order case generalises to higher derivatives. If you want to consider $k$-th order derivatives for some positive integer $k$, you can define it inductively as $d^{k}F[x_{0}] := d(d^{k-1}F)[x_{0}]$ given that enough derivatives exist for this to make sense. This defines a map $d^{k}F:U\to \mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X, \ldots \mathcal{L}(X, Y)))$, where there are $k$ occurrences of $X$ in the expression $\mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X, \ldots \mathcal{L}(X, Y)))$. By an argument involving induction on $k$, each element of $\mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X, \cdots \mathcal{L}(X, Y)))$ can be identified with an element of $\mathcal{L}^{k}(X,Y)$, where $\mathcal{L}^{k}(X,Y)$ denotes the continuous $k$-linear maps from $X$ into $Y$. It can be verified that $\mathcal{L}^{k}(X,Y)$ equipped with the norm $\|g\| := \sup \{ \|g(x_{1}, \ldots , x_{k})\|_{Y} : x_{1}, \ldots , x_{k} \in B_{X}\}$ is a Banach space because $Y$ is one. Moreover, the correspondence of each $f\in \mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X, \ldots \mathcal{L}(X, Y)))$ with some $g\in \mathcal{L}^{k}(X,Y)$ given by $g(x_{1}, \ldots , x_{k}) := [[f(x_{1})](x_{2})]\ldots (x_{k})$ is a surjective isometry.
As you can see, it is much simpler to work with $k$-linear continuous maps rather than with objects of the form $\mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{L}(X, \ldots \mathcal{L}(X, Y)))$, which is one useful reason why this is done. Another benefit is that this leads to nice formulations of other results such as Taylor's theorem.

So the proof that $\mathcal{L}^n(X,Y)$ (multilinear maps) is a Banach comes just comes from induction and the bijective isometry $\mathcal{L}(X,\mathcal{L}(X,Y)) \cong \mathcal{L}^2(X,Y)$ (actually I found out this is a natural isomorphism by the adjoint isomorphism theorem)

That is one way to show that $\mathcal{L}^{n}(X,Y)$ is a Banach space. Another way is to show it directly by taking a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{L}^{n}(X,Y)$, forming a candidate limit as a pointwise limit of that Cauchy sequence, showing that the candidate limit is continuous and multilinear, and then finally showing that the Cauchy sequence converges to that candidate limit in norm.
